# Default save address admin order

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, address

I'm trying to enable the "Save in address book" option to be Checked by default for all new orders placed by the Admin.
I've edited the file `app/design/adminhtml/default/independ/template/sales/order/create/form/address.phtml`

Which is fine on initial load. However, if I change the Dropdown and select "Add New Address" the box then un-checks itself. I'm assuming that there is some Javascript somewhere that's doing this, but I couldn't find any easily so I'm hoping someone has done this before.

Answer (score 2):

The address change is done via the js in the file `js/mage/adminhtml/sales.js`. Here you will find the function `selectAddress`. I assume that when the address is 0, that will be true when the address is new, you will end up into the function `fillAddressFields`.